# Does Allah accept a mother's bad dua' for her children?

Tags: dua, parents

Does Allah accept a mother's bad dua' for her children, even if she is so angry that she doesn't actually mean it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a mother's curse real in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/76276/is-a-mothers-curse-real-in-islam)

Answer (score 1):

as a personal experience, Allah accepts her duaa. I've read that some scholars ask mothers to be specific in their duaa and try to be much more positive because it will affect their children,

Comment: what if you have a uneducated mother who is ignorant? i guess not in that case.

Answer (score -1):

Assalamwalaykum,

I feel, a mother's bad dua will not be accepted, if she doesn't mean it.

because Allah knows what a person thinks, and what intentions they have, so if her intentions are pure, nothing will happen, a dua gets accepted only if it comes from the bottom of your heart.